# Create Table Failed Column Date DateType

Tags: wpdb, table, wp-list-table, customization

I have a plugin that creates tables and one of them is failing and I feel like it's due to either my syntax or the fact that I'm trying to create a column with datatype DATE and not TIMESTAMP (only one that I can make work).  Can someone look at my syntax below and tell me what is wrong?

```
$table = $wpdb->prefix.SSM_ACADEMIC_YEAR_TABLE;

        $sql =  "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " . $table . " (
                  id mediumint(12) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
                  description VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
                  begin_date DATE NOT NULL, 
                  end_date DATE NOT NULL
                PRIMARY KEY (id));";

    $wpdb->query($sql);
```

and now just looking at the other field in question, is it possible that it doesn't like VARCHAR(200)?  Having issues here and running out of steam and time.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after looking at the other tables I ***had*** created successfully, only difference was the `description` column.  Apparently WordPress or MySQL doesn't like that as a column name and somehow has it reserved.  So, after renaming it, the table was created fine.  Hope this helps someone else in the same boat.